# Django Nonrel Groups Issue

Tags: python, django, django-nonrel

Django Nonrel Groups Issue

Django Nonrel branch version 1.4 of Django is being used. 
Groups from: https://github.com/django-nonrel/django-permission-backend-nonrel

The admin section works fine. I am able to create groups, assign them to users.

Now adding them to the template throws an error.

```
{% for group in user.groups.all %}
    {{group.name}}

    {% endfor %}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
This query is not supported by the database.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe user.groups is a List of keys to groups.  I don't think that djangotoolbox or djangoappengine currently will generate a query for a list of keys.  You can try updating djangotoolbox to handle this case, or more easily, you can issue a query outside the template for `Group.objects.filter(id__in=user.groups)`, and then pass that into the template.